# Automatic Add Term After Theme Activation

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

This code form another topic, auto create category after theme activation

```
function create_my_cat () {
        if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) {
            require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'); 
            if ( ! get_cat_ID( 'Testimonials' ) ) {
                wp_create_category( 'Testimonials' );
            }
        }
    }

add_action ( 'after_setup_theme', 'create_my_cat' );
```

I need code to add term automatic after theme activation, example i want to add term '*rock*', '*pop*', '*dance*' to '*music*' taxonomy `after_theme_setup`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by [`wp_insert_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category) function.

eg.

```
function create_my_cat () {
    if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) {
        require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'); 
        if ( ! get_cat_ID( 'Cat Name' ) ) {
            $wpdocs_cat = array('cat_name' => 'Cat Name', 'category_description' => 'A Cool Category', 'category_nicename' => 'category-slug', 'category_parent' => '', 'taxonomy' => 'music');
            $wpdocs_cat_id = wp_insert_category($wpdocs_cat);
            echo $wpdocs_cat_id;
        }
    }
}

add_action ( 'after_setup_theme', 'create_my_cat' );
```

you can define in which category you wants to add the terms/category, eg.

```
$cat_defaults = array(
    'cat_name' => 'Category Name',
    'category_description' => 'Description',
    'category_nicename' => 'slug', // Slug
    'category_parent' => '', // If parent 
    'taxonomy' => 'category' // In which taxonomy you wants to add this category
);
```

Comment: what if the term come from custom taxonomy (not category) ? example i have taxonomy 'music' . I have post_type = post , custom_taxonomy = music. And term i want to auto added is rock, pop, and dance, can i use wp_insert_term()...?

Comment: In the array $wpdocs_cat we defined `'taxonomy'  => 'music'` so it will add category to music taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

using the [**`wp_insert_term`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) function allows us to programmatically create categories, tags, and other custom taxonomies.

```
function example_insert_category() {
    wp_insert_term(
        'Apple', // the term 
        'product', // the taxonomy
        array(
          'description' => 'A yummy apple.',
          'slug'        => 'apple'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'example_insert_category' );
```

Comment: i try this code before you answer my question, i have problem when try this code (same with your code) and that why i ask this problem here